# How to create perspective like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup, perspective

[image: a busy cat]

I really want to start creating professional mockups for my branding projects and for my portfolio but don't know how to create perspective like this.

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be to use the perspective grid tool in Illustrator and import the shapes into Photoshop as smart objects.

To do it only in Photoshop, I would use the Perspective transform tool.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new document that will hold your entire image content you're looking to adjust perspective. This can be done in any program, however, if you include text I'd suggest Illustrator or InDesign.
2. Create a Photoshop document of a slightly smaller size than the first document.
3. Goto File > Place and select the document you created in step 1.
4. Making sure that the file that's been placed is a smart object. You can be sure by confirming the small graphic overlaying the image of your new layer in the Layers Palette.
5. Cmd + T (ctrl + T on PC) and right click > Perspective.

From there you just adjust as needed. It may also help to adjust with distort as well since it has a bit more freedom than most of the other tools under transform in my opinion.

Hope this helped.